# About SublimeText Input and Buildview Package

Tags: sublimetext3

I recently installed Buildview package for Sublime Text 3 in order to move the build output to right side of my screen. And I have just installed SublimeText Input from [here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Input)

After that, my output is again being put in Console at bottom. Build output from buildview still appears but it contains only "[Finished in x.xs]". Any one know how to fix this?